# Primefaces 3.3 several fileUploads in one form

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.3. I need to use two fileUploads in advanced mode inside one form. The problem that I encounter is that when I upload some file using the first fileUpload it seems that the second fileUpload gets also activated since it shows the same file name to upload, although I don't click on the second fileUpload.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces now supports only one advanced Fileupload control in a form.